# control already disposed when returning from await

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, dispose

I am working on a big WinForms project that controls several Forms on the same UI Thread.

several of this forms has the ability to take and analyze some data from a DB, this is done using an await (for not freezing all the forms while waiting to the data and analyzing it).

I want to make sure i don't have a problem when the UI thread is continuing after an await in a disposed form (if the user closed the form while Task is still running).

I did a search in google and find this:

[How to better handle disposed controls when using async/await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31062282/how-to-better-handle-disposed-controls-when-using-async-await)

in this page the author writes that an Exception is thrown in the situation above (when the UI thread tries to access a label in a disposed form).

I did a test run of this situation and I did not get any Exception thrown:

```
    public partial class Simple_Form : Form
{
    public Simple_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public async Task startCheck(Form1 caller)
    {
        caller.richTextBox1.Text += "Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "|start\n";
        label1.Text = "Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "|start";

        await Task.Delay(10000);
        caller.richTextBox1.Text += "Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "|stop\n";
        caller.richTextBox1.Text += "Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "|" + label1.IsDisposed + "\n";
        label1.Text = "Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "|stop";
    }
```

I tried to run the StartCheck and closing the Simple_Form Form while the UI thread was in the await state.

this code running without any Exceptions thrown although the UI thread tried to change a Disposed label (label1), label1.IsDisposed was "true".

am i missing something or does this functionality changed since the creation of the page above?

Edit:

As requested, the main form i ran:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Simple_Form newForm;
    private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newForm = new Simple_Form();
        newForm.Show();

        await newForm.startCheck(this);

        return;

    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newForm.Dispose();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += "Thread:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString() + "|Still alive.\n";
    }
}
```

I am creating Simple_Form by clicking button2.

I tried disposing it by clicking button1 or by just clickinh the "X" button on the Simple_Form form, both ways worked without any Exceptions thrown.

Edit 2: Changed the code as recommended, The original question still stands.

Comment: How do you call `StartCheck`? Can you show use where you actually call `Dispose()` the form?

Comment: No problem, I Edited the original post.

Comment: You should get a warning about not awaiting the `newForm.startCheck(this);` also the `startCheck` method should return a `Task`

Comment: The reference source is our friend. Label set_Text() calls base (Control.set_Text()) and this method (setter of Text property) does not check if the instance is disposed or not: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/Control.cs,952c66876790b53a

Comment: Exception will be thrown in `startCheck` method, but because you are not awaiting for it, exception is being "swallowed".

Comment: `await Task.Delay(10000)` instead of thread sleep ;)

Comment: @Jeroen van Langen, I dont want to wait for startCheck, just check if  startCheck can complete without any Exceptions although  Simple_Form as disposed.

Comment: @Fabio I just verified with a simple (and synchronous POC). A disposed Label allows assignments to its Text property.

Comment: @Oguz Ozgul, so a label text change will not throw an Exception in this situation, what king of changes will throw an Exception in the above situation? I wan't to understanf if i have to check this.IsDisposed after every await to make sure an Exception will not be thrown if the user closed the form or this is not necessary (I don't care if the code will continue to run in the background if it will end without any problems in the end).

Comment: @YakirShlezinger this is the only sentence in your post which ends with a question mark: "am i missing something or does this functionality changed since the creation of the page above?". Of course my comment does not solve your problem of having to check if an instance on which you are waiting is disposed or not. Comments are not for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funny, that's my linked question.  Anyways, the solution is simple.  Use this pattern:

```
await Whatever();
if (IsDisposed)
    return;
```

Why is this necessary?  Well the `await` call captures the current `SynchronizationContext` and then posts back to it.

That means you're back on the original thread.  In this case, the GUI thread.

While that's happening asynchronously GUI objects can be disposed of for various reasons (most commonly a form close by the user).  Remember, `await` is **not** a blocking call.

So you should protect yourself with `IsDisposed` check(s) every single time you `await` on the GUI thread.

Specifically, check this flag on any controls modified after the `await` call in the same method (that includes `Form` which is derived from `Control`).

**However**, you need to understand how Exceptions are handled by Tasks:

If you do an `await` you can `try ... catch` around it.  If you *dont* use `await` exceptions do not bubble up.  Here's a simple example.

```
Task.Run(() => { ... });
```

This will *not* raise an exception you can catch *unless* it is awaited on.  If you aren't using `await` you can check for the exception using `Task.Exception` like so:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => { ... });
//...SNIP...
if (task.Exception != null)
    //Do something
```

Other issues with your code:

```
public async void StartCheck(Form1 caller)
```

should be

```
public async Task StartCheck(Form1 caller)
```

The *only* time an async method should not return `Task` or `Task<T>` is if you're not allowed to use that signature (like button click handlers).

Finally, use `Task.Delay` not `Thread.Sleep`.  Change

```
await Task.Run(() =>
{
    Thread.Sleep(10000);
});
```

To

```
await Task.Delay(10000);
```

**Edit**

Try this:

```
public async Task startCheck(Form1 caller)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    this.Show();
}
```

After you have closed `newForm` but before the `await` has completed.  An exception will be thrown.

This should also cause the behavior you expect:

```
newForm.Dispose(true);
```

Comment: wow, that is quite coincidence. Any way, I know this pattern will resolve this issue but i am trying to figure out 2 things: 1. Why in the code i created no Exception is thrown and what changes will throw the Exception you mentioned in your original post. 2. If this patterns is required (if i don't care that an unnecessary code  will run as long as it will end without and Exceptions).

Comment: @YakirShlezinger Read the bolded "however" portion.  Your code should be `private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { await newForm.startCheck(this); }`  This will allow you to catch the exception.  To be clear, an exception will happen either way if you dispose before the `await Task.Delay` completes, but it will not bubble up.  Please make the changes I suggest and try again and you should see an exception.

Comment: I tried making the changed you said (changing StartCheck to Task and adding await newForm.startCheck(this);), I am still getting no Exceptions.

Comment: @YakirShlezinger Are you disposing of `newForm` before the `await` completes?  if not you're fine.  If you think somethings wrong please edit the question so that we can run the code on our end.

Comment: Yes i am, label1.IsDisposed is "True" before "label1.Text =...". I edited the original question as recomended.

Comment: @YakirShlezinger Just checked the source code for `Label`.  That assignment will not throw an exception if it's disposed.  But don't rely on this behavior for all controls.  It's not a good idea to do things with disposed objects in general.  Want an exception to happen?  Add `this.Show()` at the end of `startCheck`.

Comment: Ok, Got it, Thank you very much.